# Counting Occurrences of Each Word in a Text File

Tags: c++, count

Given a large text file with multiple strings, what would be the most efficient way to read the text file and count how many occurrences of each word are there in C++? The text file's size is unknown so I cannot just use a simple array. Also, there is another catch. Each line of this text file starts with a category key word and the following words are the features of that category. I need to be able to count how many occurrences of each word is in that category.

For example:

```
colors red blue green yellow orange purple
sky blue high clouds air empty vast big
ocean wet water aquatic blue
colors brown black blue white blue blue
```

With this example, I need to count that within the "**colors**" category, there are 4 occurrences of "**blue**", even though there are 6 total occurrences of blue in total.

Comment: Please show an example of what you have done so far.

Comment: Like @chux said, give us some code to work with.

Comment: I disagree with the decision to close this question. The intent of the question seems quite clear to me starting with the final two sentences of the first paragraph. And the OP's example and final sentence that follow are perfectly adequate. Finally, I do believe that the example output that I provided in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16868853/1497596) is a match for that which the OP desires. The answers provided by others also indicate to me an understanding of the heart of the question.

Answer (score 6):

I would use a [stream](/questions/tagged/stream) for reading and separating the words (it separates words by looking for whitespace) and save them to a [dictionary](/questions/tagged/dictionary) (The standard C++ method is to use [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)).

Here is a C++ documented code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map> // A map will be used to count the words.
#include <fstream> // Will be used to read from a file.
#include <string> // The map's key value.
using namespace std;


//Will be used to print the map later.
template <class KTy, class Ty>
void PrintMap(map<KTy, Ty> map)
{
    typedef std::map<KTy, Ty>::iterator iterator;
    for (iterator p = map.begin(); p != map.end(); p++)
        cout << p->first << ": " << p->second << endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    static const char* fileName = "C:\\MyFile.txt";

    // Will store the word and count.
    map<string, unsigned int> wordsCount;


    {
        // Begin reading from file:
        ifstream fileStream(fileName);

        // Check if we've opened the file (as we should have).
        if (fileStream.is_open())
            while (fileStream.good())
            {
                // Store the next word in the file in a local variable.
                string word;
                fileStream >> word;

                //Look if it's already there.
                if (wordsCount.find(word) == wordsCount.end()) // Then we've encountered the word for a first time.
                    wordsCount[word] = 1; // Initialize it to 1.
                else // Then we've already seen it before..
                    wordsCount[word]++; // Just increment it.
            }
        else  // We couldn't open the file. Report the error in the error stream.
        {
            cerr << "Couldn't open the file." << endl;
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        // Print the words map.
        PrintMap(wordsCount);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

air: 1 
    aquatic: 1 
    big: 1 
    black: 1 
    blue: 6 
    brown: 1 
    clouds: 1 
    colors: 2 
    empty: 1 
    green: 1 
    high: 1 
    ocean: 1 
    orange: 1 
    purple: 1 
    red: 1 
    sky: 1 
    vast: 1 
    water: 1 
    wet: 1 
    white: 1 
    yellow: 1

Comment: The `if` condition is not required. In map you don't need to check if the word already there or not. map automatically adds the word if it is not present. Just add: `wordsCount[word]++;` remove the if part.

Answer (score 2):

Tokenize the words and store them as key-value pairs.

UPDATE: I realized that I have misread the question. Following code should separate and count by categories:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream file;
    file.open("path\\to\\text\\file");
    if(!file.is_open()) return 1;
    map<string, map<string, int> > categories;
    while(file.good())
    {
        string s;
        getline(file, s);
        int pos = s.find_first_of(' ');
        if(pos < 0) continue;
        string word = s.substr(0, pos);
        string category = word;
        s = s.erase(0, pos+1);
        while(s.size() > 0)
        {
            pos = s.find_first_of(' ');
            if(pos < 0)
                pos = s.size();
            string word = s.substr(0, pos);
            if(word != "")
                categories[category][word]++;
            s = s.erase(0, pos+1);
        }
    }
    for(map<string, map<string, int> >::iterator cit = categories.begin(); cit != categories.end(); ++cit)
    {
        cout << "Category - " << cit->first << endl;
        for(map<string, int>::iterator wit = cit->second.begin(); wit != cit->second.end(); ++wit)
            cout << "\tword: " << wit->first << ",\t" << wit->second << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Update 2: Chris asked for a modification of the algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream file;
    file.open("D:\\Documents\\txt.txt");
    if(!file.is_open()) return 1;
    map<string, int> categories;
    while(file.good())
    {
        string s;
        getline(file, s);
        int pos = s.find_first_of(' ');
        if(pos < 0) continue;
        while(s.size() > 0)
        {
            pos = s.find_first_of(' ');
            if(pos < 0)
                pos = s.size();
            string word = s.substr(0, pos);
            if(word != "")
                categories[word]++;
            s = s.erase(0, pos+1);
        }
    }
    for(map<string, int>::iterator wit = categories.begin(); wit != categories.end(); ++wit)
        cout << "word: " << wit->first << "\t" << wit->second << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey, I like your code. would you know how to get ride of the initial category sorter? I have a list of 500 words that do not have categories, and I do not want to have to put a random character in front of each word to make it work. Also, is there any way to make it give a list of all the words that have 10+ instances?

Comment: Hi Chris, to achieve that you only need to have map<string, int>, no need for encapsulating map. To get words with 10+ instances you would just put condition like if (wit->second >= 10) ...

Comment: Hi Filip.  I am quite new to C++, and am having problems making that modification to the code.  Is there any way you could do that, and then post it here?  I would really appreciate it.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Chris, I added modified answer that you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that achieves your stated objective. [See it live here](http://codepad.org/h8GPWEXz).

It makes use of `std::map` to maintain a count of the number of times that a **(category, word)** pair occurs.

`std::istringstream` is used to break the data first into rows, and then into words.

---

**OUTPUT:**

```
(colors, black) => 1
(colors, blue) => 4
(colors, brown) => 1
(colors, green) => 1
(colors, orange) => 1
(colors, purple) => 1
(colors, red) => 1
(colors, white) => 1
(colors, yellow) => 1
(ocean, aquatic) => 1
(ocean, blue) => 1
(ocean, water) => 1
(ocean, wet) => 1
(sky, air) => 1
(sky, big) => 1
(sky, blue) => 1
(sky, clouds) => 1
(sky, empty) => 1
(sky, high) => 1
(sky, vast) => 1
```

**PROGRAM:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // std::cout, std::endl
#include <map>       // std::map
#include <sstream>   // std::istringstream
#include <utility>   // std::pair

int main()
{
    // The data.
    std::string content =
        "colors red blue green yellow orange purple\n"
        "sky blue high clouds air empty vast big\n"
        "ocean wet water aquatic blue\n"
        "colors brown black blue white blue blue\n";

    // Load the data into an in-memory table.
    std::istringstream table(content);

    std::string row;
    std::string category;
    std::string word;
    const char delim = ' ';
    std::map<pair<std::string, std::string>, long> category_map;
    std::pair<std::string, std::string> cw_pair;
    long count;

    // Read each row from the in-memory table.
    while (!table.eof())
    {
        // Get a row of data.
        getline(table, row);

        // Allow the row to be read word-by-word.
        std::istringstream words(row);

        // Get the first word in the row; it is the category.
        getline(words, category, delim);

        // Get the remaining words in the row.
        while (std::getline(words, word, delim)) {
            cw_pair = std::make_pair(category, word);

            // Maintain a count of each time a (category, word) pair occurs.
            if (category_map.count(cw_pair) > 0) {
                category_map[cw_pair] += 1;
            } else {
                category_map[cw_pair] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

   // Print out each unique (category, word) pair and
   // the number of times that it occurs.
   std::map<pair<std::string, std::string>, long>::iterator it;

   for (it = category_map.begin(); it != category_map.end(); ++it) {
       cw_pair = it->first;
       category = cw_pair.first;
       word = cw_pair.second;
       count = it->second;

       std::cout << "(" << category << ", " << word << ") => "
           << count << std::endl;
   }
}
```