# Problems with strings C++

Tags: c++, string, search, loops

I can't figure out how to read in a few paragraphs or so, than put each word in the structure, than count how many unique words there are.

I know how to read in the data just not transfer a word from the string that has a line. And as I said before read in a few paragraphs

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;


struct words
{
    char unique[21];
    int count;
} test;

void inputFile (words essay[100]);
int search (int index, int subscript, int integer,words essay[100]);

int main()
{
    words essay[100];
    inputFile (&test);

    cout << essay[0].unique<<test.count;
    return 0;
}


void inputFile (words essay[100])
{
    char fileName[81];
    char copyName[81];
    cout << "What is the name of the input file? \n";
    cin >> fileName;


    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;
    int count = 0;
    char line [81];
    int ch;
    infile.open(fileName);
    outfile.open(copyName);

    while ((ch = infile.peek()) != EOF)
    {   // while not end of file
        infile.getline (line[81].unique, 81);
        cout << "Copying: " << line << endl;


        count++;
        outfile << essay << endl;
    }

    cout << "There were " << count << " lines copied\n";
    cout << endl;
    // close both files
    infile.close ();
    outfile.close ();
 };


/*int search (int index, int subscript, int integer, struct words essay[100])
{
    string key;
    key = test.unique;
    int n;
    n = test.count;
    int i;
    i = 0;
    while (i < n && essay[i] != key)
    i++;
    if (i == n)
    {
        i = -1;
    }
    return i;
    };*/
```

Comment: does that code compile ? at the first look it should not... FYI, counting word in a text is an easy task and a lot of answer describe how to do it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867944/counting-occurrences-of-each-word-in-a-text-file

Comment: You don't have to peek. Just write `while (infile.getline(…)) { … }`. Btw `line[81].unique` makes no sense; what are you trying to do there? Whatever the case, you should just define `line` as a `std::string` and use `std::getline(infile, line)` instead of `infile.getline(…)`.

Comment: Why if you explicitly talks about C++ strings, includes cstring? Use `std::string` (Header <string>)

Comment: It should compile yes and ill check out that link.

The line[81].unique was my fault, I was trying something before and did not fix it apparently, I was trying to read the file into the struct, just trying different things cause I couldnt get it to work.

The book we have just has the cstring in the example so I figured I had to include it.
Thanks again

Comment: @alexbuisson the link didnt help cause they use maps, I can not use that, I get the concept of what they are doing I just dont get how to take the string I read in (i can read in the data just fine) and than separate into words in the struct

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer, primary focused on cleaning up the stream-reading logic. I cannot figure out what you are doing with enough clarity to offer any more help. (E.g., why are you outputting `essay` to `outfile` without having put anything in it.)

```
void inputFile (words essay[100])
{
    std::string fileName, copyName;
    cout << "What is the name of the input file?\n";
    cin >> fileName;
    // I assume you get copyName here…
    // Though fileName and copyName really should be parameters
    // passed in from `main()`.

    ifstream infile(fileName);
    ofstream outfile(copyName);
    std::string line;
    int count = 0;
    while (getline(infile, line))
    {
        cout << "Copying: " << line << endl;
        count++;
        outfile << essay << endl; // No idea what you're doing here.
    }

    cout << "There were " << count << " lines copied\n";
};
```

Comment: that is just supposed to output what was "copied" which I can do that, I just dont understand how to take what I copy (input) than put each individual word in the struct and count the unique ones.

Comment: I know I will need a for loop I just dont know how to get it to separate the white space so you have each individual word in the structure.