# How can I find the number of words in a list?

Tags: c++

Hey guys I have this assignment I'm working on and I need some help with this question. I was given a text document with thousands of words and I have to find the number of words of every possible length and print how many there are in a table. This is what I got so far

```
inStream.open("EnglishWords.txt", ifstream::in);

string word; 
//int number of letters;
//int number of words;

while (inStream) {

    inStream >> word;
    if (word.length() == //Something..)
        //print << number of letters << number of words;

}
```

So I basically have nothing. Any of you guys able to help me out here? or give me direction of how i should start?

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look into a tutorial or a book along the lines of introduction to coding. Some basic concept might have their potential use here become obvious.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting Occurrences of Each Word in a Text File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867944/counting-occurrences-of-each-word-in-a-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can make an `std::map` which stores two `int`s and do this:

```
std::map<int, int> map;

while (inStream) {
    map[word.length()]++; // increment number of words for given length
}
```

then to print all the words of each length, you can make a `for` loop:

```
for (auto i = 0; i < MAX_LENGTH; ++i) {
    std::cout << "words of length " << i << ": " << map[i] << '\n';
}
```

I haven't tested it but this is just an idea.

P.S. Edits made thanks to Ben who cleared up the question's purpose.

Comment: Its number of words with a length, so i think `std::map<int, int>` and `map[word.length]++` would be sufficient.